# How to open the image path if there are some image cannot open? PIL python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

as u can see 9.jpg cannot open.
when i use

```
 im = Image.open(imagepath)
```

error:
IOError: cannot identify image file 'C:\Desktop\Tom_Cruise\images\9.jpg

So how to ignore it or how to solve the error???

[image]

Comment: can you actually view this image? Since there is no preview, it could be just a corrupted file (or wrong extension)

Comment: i cannot view this image. so how to solve or ignore the error, since the img is auto download from website

Comment: @bob90937 did my answer work for you? Please choose to accept as an answer at your discretion.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a `try-except` block to get around `IOError`?

```
try:
    im = Image.open(imagepath)
except IOError:
    print '%s could not be opened' % imagepath
```